# Entity Framework Composite Key

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I have a database with two tables, customer and account. Because multiple customers can exist on multiple accounts this is a many to many design.

This is how I designed it in SQL

[image]

This works quite nicely as Entity Framework picks up that its a mapping table and just maps Customer to Account as lists on each and hiding the mapping table. Brilliant!

I would like to extend this further to add preferences to a mapping between a customer and an account like such:

[image]

Am I right in assuming this is not possible? I have tried adding it to EF model but instead it brings back the mapping table.

Anyone else had any luck with this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. It looks pretty simple to achieve.

Comment: See above for what I have tried, I'm not sure how else to explain it. And yes it looks pretty simple but I'm not sure if Entity Framework supports it.

Comment: After a bit more thought, I don't believe this is possible. In the first instance EF is just mapping a many to many relationship. But with the inclusion of the preferences it couldn't be assigned to any individual entity and would need to show the mapping table. oh well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your first case is a simple many to many relation table, which in Entity Framework results in the collections of entities on one another.

If you want to have a relation to the `Preference` from your `CustomerAccount` relation table, the relation becomes complex and it cannot be depicted in the simple relation lists anymore. You need add an entity for your relation `CustomerAccount` which will have foreign keys on `Customer`, `Account` and `Preference`.

Comment: This is correct, the reason behind me wanting to do it with one mapping table with the composite key was to try and make a preference entry be required for mapping between a customer and account.